# What are prerequisites for importing Android compatibility library packages?

Tags: android

I'm trying to import ACL Fragment packages into Fragment tutorial project for API 4 in Eclipse, but get red underline error indication (see image):

[Errors](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/_JKye7RjwhNE/TdtLTJ4dxyI/AAAAAAAAAf0/70GdCZdNkk4/error.jpg)

I've ran Eclipse update and have installed these packages in AVD (see image):

[Installed packages](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/_JKye7RjwhNE/TdtLS0sXQjI/AAAAAAAAAfw/J3LAg4Mt7Sw/installed%20packages.jpg)

What am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for answers. For those noobs (like me) who dont know how to add JAR to project build path, here is simple directions I've found: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `android-support-v4.jar` to you project. You can find this jar at `yoursdkpath/extras/android/compatibility/v4/`.

Referring to [Using Fragment of Android Compatibility Package](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-fragment-of-android-compatibility.html) may help you.

Answer (score 3):

There is a page on the Android Developers web site about this called [Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

Here is how to get the Android Compatibility Package.

In Eclipse go to `Window > Android SDK Manager`. Look under `Extras > Android Support Package`. If it is not installed then install it. This will install the support packages needed for developing fragments on older versions of Android

Normally you would then Right click on your project and select `Android Tools > Add Compatibility Library...` but this seems to be broken at the moment as it does not look in your configured android SDK directory. Instead you need to add the library manually as described in the section [Setting Up a Project to Use a Library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html#SettingUp). Now you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks for posting that link, @JosephL.  I am pretty new to this package myself and was having trouble finding up-to-date general documentation on it, probably because I didn't know that they renamed it from the "Compatibility Package" to the "Support Package."

Answer (score 0):

Have you added ACL's jar file to your project's build path?